# Force partition pruning with IN statement and select for update in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

Would be glad if you could help me out:
Got a query that is supposed to take some task from the database (Postgres) partitioned table (partitioned by execute_ts) and take them to work thread-safely (with several workers in the service taking the tasks of the DB concurrently)

```
UPDATE tasks
SET    status = 'IN_WORK' 
WHERE  execute_ts BETWEEN (now() - INTERVAL '2 day') AND now() 
    AND id IN (
     SELECT id
     FROM   tasks
     WHERE  status IN ('INITIAL', 'TO_BE_RETRIED')
      AND execute_ts BETWEEN (now() - INTERVAL '2 day') AND now()
LIMIT  1000
 FOR    UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
    )
RETURNING *;
```

Is there a way to avoid repeating `execute_ts BETWEEN (now() - INTERVAL '2 day') AND now()` conditions, because otherwise it traverses all partitions.

Comment: Why are you using a subquery and ids at all? Why not just write `UPDATE … WHERE status IN ('INITIAL', 'TO_BE_RETRIED') AND execute_ts BETWEEN (now() - INTERVAL '2 day') AND now()`?

Comment: What do you mean by "*thread-safely*"?

Comment: I mean that if several workers gather the tasks using the query - it would be safe

Comment: I think that sub-`SELECT` only makes sense when you add a `LIMIT` clause or something similar. Otherwise, it is my understanding that `UPDATE tasks SET status = 'IN_WORK' 
WHERE  status IN ('INITIAL', 'TO_BE_RETRIED') AND … RETURNING *` will never return the same row twice, even if executed many times from concurrent sessions.

Comment: let me edit it to have the limit of 1000 rows

Comment: You could try `WHERE (execute_ts, id) IN (SELECT execute_ts, id FROM …)`

Answer (score 0):

The [tuple identifier `ctid`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-system-columns.html) is a good way to achieve an efficient self-join. However, according to [this question on DBA.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/214422/188406) one needs to combine it with the `tableoid` to work correctly in partitioned tables, and one should use a CTE instead of a subquery:

```
WITH work AS (
  SELECT tableoid, ctid
  FROM   tasks
  WHERE  status IN ('INITIAL', 'TO_BE_RETRIED')
    AND  execute_ts BETWEEN (now() - INTERVAL '2 day') AND now()
  LIMIT  1000
  FOR    UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
)
UPDATE tasks
SET    status = 'IN_WORK'
WHERE  (tableoid, ctid) IN (TABLE work)
RETURNING *;
```

Comment: the optimizer plan says that it gonna traverse all the partitions

Comment: CTE part alone when analyzed uses pruning but the outer part with the UPDATE makes it go through all partitions

Comment: Aw shucks. I'll write up the other approach I mentioned in the comments then

Answer (score -1):

To avoid repeating the `execute_ts` conditional expression, you could just match the exact `execute_ts` values from the subquery result:

```
UPDATE tasks
SET    status = 'IN_WORK'
WHERE  (execute_ts, id) IN (
  SELECT execute_ts, id
  FROM   tasks
  WHERE  status IN ('INITIAL', 'TO_BE_RETRIED')
    AND  execute_ts BETWEEN (now() - INTERVAL '2 day') AND now()
  LIMIT  1000
  FOR    UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
)
RETURNING *;
```

Or, [as recommended](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/69497/188406), with a CTE:

```
WITH work AS (
  SELECT execute_ts, id
  FROM   tasks
  WHERE  status IN ('INITIAL', 'TO_BE_RETRIED')
    AND  execute_ts BETWEEN (now() - INTERVAL '2 day') AND now()
  LIMIT  1000
  FOR    UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
)
UPDATE tasks
SET    status = 'IN_WORK'
WHERE  (execute_ts, id) IN (TABLE work)
RETURNING *;
```